# Installing rpm packages using chef (with dependencies)

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have a list of rpm packages including dependencies. Locally I do rpm -i *.rpm and it works fine. How do I use the -i flag when I use chef's rpm_package resource. I cant use yum as we are trying something that works offline.

Just need a chef way for rpm -i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

### Bash it

Just like you did in your question, you can use the `bash` resource to execute the rpm command. This is **not** idempotent by default and is (obviously) not cross-platform:

```rb
bash 'rpm -i *.rpm' do
  cwd '/path/to/that/directory'
end
```

### Ruby it

Slightly less straightforward, you can use Ruby's native file system functions to traverse the tree:

```rb
Dir['/path/to/rpms/*.rpm'].each do |path|
  rpm_package File.basename(path) do
    source path
  end
end
```

This will iterate over each item in the given path that matches the glob.

Comment: Cool thanks Seth.. I just wanted to check if there is anyway of doing it with the package resource since I did a lot of reading and could not find any.