# Install Locally placed packages (.rpm) from a chef cookbook

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, cookbook

I have to install mysql on Red hat Linux machine using Chef Cookbook. Problem is that my Linux Vm (node) don't have internet connection.

So i need to install a mysql package that is placed on Linux machine using Chef cookbook. I need to write cookbook to install mysql rpm.

I didn't get this solution: [Installing rpm packages using chef (with dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22913065/installing-rpm-packages-using-chef-with-dependencies)

please show me correct path.
Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_rpm_package.html)

> `source`   Ruby Type: String
>
> Optional. The path to a package in the local file system.

So it's as simple as giving the correct path into the resource definition:

```
rpm_package "package name" do
  source "/path/to/package_file.rpm"
end
```